# Navigating windows folder on Ubuntu partition

Tags: mount, dual-boot

I have a dual boot Win7/Ubuntu LTS. I can "see" all my Win7 files on a mounted directory "OS" via the filemanager. I want to navigate this directory through the command line. I tried but I'm clueless how to "cd" into this mounted partition, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the directory is usually `/media/< Partition name >`

You can check the mounted partitions and their mount points by running the command

`df`

or the command

`mount -l | grep dev/*`

And then you can cd to that directory using the terminal.

Note: Ubuntu usually mounts the partitions when you click on them in Nautilus, the file manager. So remember to click on it before running `df`